# Is it worth using consumer grade speakers to do surround sound design?

Tags: sound-design, mixing, speakers, 5.1

I was wondering what options I have for getting a basic 5.1 mixing setup in my house for under £100-£200. I know that might sound mad but I'm only looking for something to get started on to do some basic mixes in 5.1. I've not currently got the money for much more than that. I do Sound Design at college where I have access to the top quality equipment but that will soon be over. I was looking at the logitech Z506 Setup but I'm not sure if I should bother buying "watch movies on your computer" quality speakers. What options do I have for mixing surround sound on a budget?

Comment: Not sure I see this as a home theatre question - it's on how to continue sound design efforts after finishing college, thereby losing the nice free facility.

Comment: I modified it to be a bit more on topic and less product recommendation like and re-opened since I do think there is a sound design related question here.